# How to split a string into letters and integers and refer to letter to another csv file for a mathematical equation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different csv files:

First csv file is my main one: data1.csv:

```
col1,col2,col3
4,a1 b3,15
6,c5 d6,12
1,e2 f3 g2,21
```

I want to split col2 into letter and integer and put them into equation and create a new column from these values. For example, for row1 and row 3 equations would be:

`1*a+3*b` and `2*e+3*f+2*g` .

For a, b, c, d, e, f, g value I want to extract them from second csv file for example column2 automatically:

data2.csv:

```
colx,coly,colz
a,12,4
b,1,5
c,2,6
d,7,3
e,8,8
f,4,6
g,3,11
```

I could so far split text into list and separated single them further into letter and digit but I could not figure out how to refer second csv file with letter. How can I do with pandas dataframe? Suggestions and helps are appreciated.

Comment: Where's `f` in data2? And why is it `g*2` instead of `g+2` - you really need to describe some rules here and if possible show what you've got so far so we folks can help correct your attempt.

Comment: Thanks. I just put it. Sorry also @JonClements

I could not write the equation there properly. for example for row 1, it'll be a*1+b*3. I could not manage the put multiplication symbol there. Well the issue I could just read the both csv files and since I could not create the equation from the column and also refer to the second file, there is not much left to put here

Comment: `sympy` would be of some help, you need to format your cells as equations though

Comment: Which of the columns from data2 would you substitute for the letters?  `coly` or `colz`?  Or would you have two new dataframe columns in data1?

Comment: Thanks @SRawson for comment. I want to use coly values from second column for the equation.

Comment: try df.assign(new_col_name=lambda df_ : df_.col2 + df_.col3)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the cleanest, but it does the job!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [4, 6, 1],
                      'col2': ['a1 b3', 'c5 d6', 'e2 f3 g2'],
                      'col3': [15, 12, 21]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'colx': list('abcdefg'),
                      'coly': [12, 1, 2, 7, 8, 4, 3],
                      'colz': [4, 5, 6, 3, 8, 6, 11]})

mapping = data2.set_index("colx")["coly"].to_dict()
#mapping output: {'a': 12, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 7, 'e': 8, 'f': 4, 'g': 3}
```

Split `col2`:

```
df = data1['col2'].str.split('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)', expand=True).replace([""," ",None], np.nan).dropna(how='all',axis=1)
df
#Out:
#   1  2  4  5    7    8
#0  a  1  b  3  NaN  NaN
#1  c  5  d  6  NaN  NaN
#2  e  2  f  3    g    2
```

Computation:

```
# replace all np.nan with string
df.replace(np.nan, "apple", inplace=True)
# map any letters with mapping dictionary
for j, i in df.iteritems():
    # don't map digits
    if any(i.str.isdigit()):
        df[j] = i
    # map strings
    else:
        df[j] = i.map(mapping)
# replace all apple values with np.nan
df.replace("apple", np.nan, inplace=True)
# convert all items in df to numeric
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

`"apple"` here is generic, so that np.nan doesn't cause `isdigit` to be True.

Finally:

```
# multiply together the odd columns with even, and sum
result = df.iloc[:,::2].mul(df.iloc[:,1::2].values).sum(axis=1)
# new data1 column with the result
data1["result"] = result

data1
#Out: 
#   col1      col2  col3  result
#0     4     a1 b3    15    15.0
#1     6     c5 d6    12    52.0
#2     1  e2 f3 g2    21    34.0
```